# how to add primary key to text datatype in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to apply primary key on the text fields in android database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591492/is-it-possible-to-apply-primary-key-on-the-text-fields-in-android-database)

I have done like these getting force close.

```
private static final String CREATE_NEWCUSTOMER = "create table newcustomer (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "cname text primary key, date text , " + "caddress text);";
```

it working for integer if any have idea please help me.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591492/is-it-possible-to-apply-primary-key-on-the-text-fields-in-android-database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't create primary keys like that in SQLite. I have not tested the following, but according to the documentation it should work:

```
private static final String CREATE_NEWCUSTOMER = "create table newcustomer (_id integer autoincrement, cname text, date text, caddress text, PRIMARY KEY(_id, cname));";
```

Comment: it is working but cname column taking doublicate values

Comment: Of course it does! The `cname` column alone is not unique. It's only unique in combination with the `_id` column, as they both belong to the primary key. As the `_id` column is `autoincrement`, you get a unique combination for every value of `cname`. However, your question was not how to make the `cname` column unique.

Answer (score 3):

You can add primary key attribute to text without any problem. In your query above there is a major problem. You can not apply attribute 'AutoIncrement' if your Primary key is composed of more than one column.

- **AUTOINCREMENT not allowed if primary key is over two or more columns**

Here is an example query that creates a table with a primary key which is comprised on two columns, one column has Integer datatype and other has text `PRIMARY KEY ("col_1", "col_2")`.

```
CREATE TABLE "Table_Name" ("col_1" INTEGER NOT NULL , "col_2" TEXT NOT NULL , "col_3" TEXT, "col_4" VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY ("col_1", "col_2"))
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
final String CREATE_TABLE_JobTime = 
    "CREATE TABLE jt (q_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,description VARCHAR);";
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_JobTime);
```

Comment: He is clearly asking about Primary key on TEXT field, its missing in your provided solution.

Comment: AUTOINCREMENT never applies to the text primary key, its only implemented on integer values

Comment: What happens if there is no "AUTOINCREMENT" used? Meaning just "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" ? I see it in code on some app, and I wonder if it can cause issues, at least for for creating a new item without specifying the ID value...