# text as primarykey in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to apply primary key on the text fields in android database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591492/is-it-possible-to-apply-primary-key-on-the-text-fields-in-android-database)

```
private static final String CREATE_NEWCUSTOMER = 
                "create table newcustomer (_id integer  autoincrement, " + 
                "cname text  , date text , " + "caddress text);";
```

in this how can I use `cname` as the primary key.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591492/is-it-possible-to-apply-primary-key-on-the-text-fields-in-android-database

Answer (score 0):

write...

```
cname text primary key not null
```

Comment: From my understanding, Android expects there to be an _id in many situations... I could be wrong, but I have in the past tried to use a cursor (to populate an AutoCompleteText field) and it fell apart because the returned query didn't have an _id column in it.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you will always need to have "_id" in the results of any query that you run (I'm not actually sure if it needs to be a primary key, but I think that's the idea.)

If you really want to have cname as a primary key but keep it labeled *cname* (not _id) in your database, you could do the following:

```
SELECT cname AS _id, date, caddress FROM newcustomer
```

I have done that before when I knew the text field was ALWAYS going to be unique. But there's the condition that you will need to make sure that cname is always unique, you could run into problems otherwise. I'd still recommend having an _id column as an integer though and using that.