# Is it possible using String as PrimaryKey in Android Room

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I use uuid in my java backend server. So I need to use that uuid in room android to make sure entities are sync'd properly.
I am aware of [Is it possible to apply primary key on the text fields in android database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591492/is-it-possible-to-apply-primary-key-on-the-text-fields-in-android-database) and  [text as primarykey in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207134/text-as-primarykey-in-android). I want to create something like this

```
@Entity(tableName = CrewColumns.TABLE_NAME)
@TypeConverters(BigDecimalConverter::class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Crew() {
    constructor (uuid: String) : this() {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    /**
     * The unique ID of the item.
     */
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = CrewColumns.UUID)
    var uuid: String = ""
    @ColumnInfo(name = CrewColumns.NAME)
    var name: String = ""
}
```

Will it be a problem with Room (DAO etc)? Thank you.

Comment: You certainly can use a string as a primary key. What specific problem did you encounter when you tried it?

Comment: @CommonsWare Currently none.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `String` as a `@PrimaryKey`.

Additionally, I also recommend making use of Kotlin's `data class` to simplify your entities. For example:

```
@Entity
data class Crew(@PrimaryKey val uuid: String, val name: String) {
    // Put any functions or other members not initialized by the constructor here
}
```

Comment: @juanmeanwhile how about for kotlin? does we have to annotate the **NonNull** as well?

Comment: @mochadwi No need since the language already have a way of indicating that the String is not nullable.

Comment: What will be the return type if an insert is performed and the primary key is of type String, could it be of type String as well? like, show below?

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    Single<String> insert(Crew crew);